# Vue router vs Express Backend

Tags: express, vue.js

Hi Im new into the web developing world and wanted to know whats the difference between using the vue router and Express. Im developing a simple web application and wondered if express is really necessary.

Comment: vue router = frontend, express = backend

Answer (score 2):

The short version is:

- **Vue router**: For single Page Apps (SPA) with client side rendered content
- **Express route**:  Not SPA, and content can be rendered in server side

When you are using Vue router, changing url path doesn't actually changing what page you are on, for example, you have `/` and `/profile` path, when you are navigating from `/` to `/profile` you are still in the same page, but Vue will render different Vue template depending on your Vue router configuration, which means the page on the browser isn't refreshed, only the URL path, and HTML DOM is changed. And all of this is being done in front-end javascript.

And when you are using express, it works like traditional Server side rendered page, where client / browser send a request to the server (express), server check what route it is, and send the HTML back to the client.

Of course this is not always the case, sometimes people use both Client Side rendering and Server side rendering depending on their needs.

This question is more like the difference between Client Side rendering, and Server Side rendering.